# Create comma seperated list from IEnumerable list of objects

Tags: c#-4.0

I have following code:

```
IEnumerable<token> token;
token = abc.GetToken(bcd); // this gets a list of guid tokens.
```

I need to get all tokens from this converted into a comma seperated list. Like
guid1, guid2, guid2... Is there a single line code to do this? Or i will have to iterate through IEnumerable list and add it as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps?

```
string csv = string.Join(",", token);
```

Assuming that your class `token` has overridden `ToString` accordingly.

Comment: I tried this already but got an error. "Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ABC.CD.Token>' is not assignable to parameter type 'string[]'."

Comment: Succinct answer is succinct.

Comment: @NoviceMe: Can you show your `token` class? You could also select the property you want to join with comma, f.e. `string.Join(",", token.Select(t=>t.Value));` (assuming that there's a `Value` property which returns the `GUID`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I used what you said above. But now get different error: "Arugument 'System.Collections.IEnumerable<string>' is not assignable to parameter type 'string[]'."

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I got it, i just needed token.ToArray(). It worked thanks!

Comment: @NoviceMe: Yes, you have already mentioned that. But the error is not directly related to my code. You need to provide more informations on your type `token`, your variable `abc` and your method `GetToken`. **Edit** Hmm, since you're using .NET 4 you can use [**`string.Join`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) with any kind of `IEnumerable`, hence i don't understand why you need `ToArray`. But the main thing is that it works now :)